# CSS isolation is not working in a Blazor component that resides in a subfolder of a pages

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am having a problem with CSS isolation in .NET Core.

It works fine if both myfile.razor and myfile.razor.css are in the Pages folder.

However, it does not work if I place **myfile.razor** in the **Pages/Homepage** folder and its corresponding CSS file in **Pages/Homepage/myfile.razor.css**

Comment: Create a [mre] from one of the Blazor templates. Detail what "does not work" means.

Comment: There's probably something you aren't telling us, as this works as advertised.  Here's my test project for your problem [on Github] - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO75687637.  Try doing a `Rebuild` of your project.

Comment: @mrc-aka-shaun-curtis thanks Its my mistake I applied a style to the 'validation-message' class in the parent component. Actually, this class was generated from the predefined 'ValidationMessage' component.